On Zassenhaus' automorphism conjecture
Zassenhaus conjectured that

if $G$ is a finite group and $\theta:\mathbb ZG\to\mathbb ZG$ is a ring automorphism that commutes with the standard augmentation, then there are a group automorphism $\alpha:G\to G$ and an invertible element $u\in\mathbb QG$ such that $\theta(g)=u\alpha(g)u^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$.

As far as I can tell, this is still open, although many special cases are known to be true. For example, Peterson proved it when $G$ is a symmetric group $S_n$, Giambruno-Sehgal-Valenti when $G$ is a wreath product $A\wr S_n$ with $A$ abelian, Parmenter-Sehgal and Giambriuno-Sehgal when $G$ is $P\wr S_n$ with $P$ a $p$-group, and Valenti when $G$ is $S_n\wr S_m$. The book Units in integral group rings by Sudershan Sehgal has a lot of information and references about this.
People look at this type of problems with $\mathbb Z$ as ground ring for important reasons, but:

Question: is it known when the version of the conjecture for group algebras with coefficents in a field (or just $\mathbb Q$, really) is true/false?

Later. As Jeremy notes in his answer, if the field big is enough (and $\mathbb Q$ is big enough for some groups) and the group has few automorphisms the version of the conjecture for fields is false. The question in my mind was really, what is the boundary between the groups for which this works and those for which it doesn't. For example, the version over $\mathbb Q$ of the conjecture is true for dihedral groups —  [G. Peterson, On the Automorphism Group of an Integral Group Ring, Illinois J. of Math., 21, 4(1977), 836 - 844.] and [S. P. Coelho, C. Polcino Milies, Boll. Unione Mat. Ital., VII. Ser., A 9, No. 3, 541–548] — and there are a few other cases I've found treated, but nothing general.

I'll note that the condition of commuting with augmentation is a nonsignificant restriction over $\Bbb Z$: if $\theta$ is arbitrary isomorphism $\Bbb Z[G] \to \Bbb Z[H]$, then if $\theta$ is defined by its restriction to basis $f: G \to \Bbb Z[H]$, then $\theta'$, defined by $g \mapsto \epsilon(g) \epsilon (f(g)) f(g)$ is an isomorphism over $\Bbb Z$; it's easy to prove that $\theta'$ is iso, because there are not much units in $\Bbb Z$.

If $G$ is abelian, then we may as well take $u=1$, so the automorphisms that you are considering are precisely those induced by group automorphisms of $G$.
But even for some small cyclic groups $G$, there are more ring automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}G$ that commute with augmentation than there are group automorphisms of $G$.
For example, if $G=C_6$, then $G$ has only two automorphisms, but $\mathbb{Q}G$ has eight automorphisms that commute with augmentation.

Yeah, I should have mentioned these examples. For bigger fields it becomes more violent: over a splitting field the group algebra of a cyclic group has factorially many automorphisms, say. Thanks.
